# Existe como alinhar um texto justificado no PhpWord?

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de alinhar um texto com phpWord da seguinte forma:

`$doc->addText('Meu texto justificado', array('size' => 9), array('align' => 'justify'`)

Mas ele não alinha o texto, vi que no lugar de `justify` posso usar o `both` mas também não obtive o resultado justificado. Alinhar a esquerda e direita funcionam. Não existe nenhuma forma de justificar um texto no phpWord?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que encontrei garimpando na internet não existe o parâmetro *justify*.

Se entrar no diretório `src\PhpWord\SimpleType\Jc.php` encontrará:

```
const START = 'start';
const CENTER = 'center';
const END = 'end';
const BOTH = 'both';
const MEDIUM_KASHIDA = 'mediumKashida';
const DISTRIBUTE = 'distribute';
const NUM_TAB = 'numTab';
const HIGH_KASHIDA = 'highKashida';
const LOW_KASHIDA = 'lowKashida';
const THAI_DISTRIBUTE = 'thaiDistribute';
```

A opção que chega mais próxima de `justify` é a `distribute`, se não me engano o problema será na última linha.

Tente e me dê um *feedback*

Comment: Realmente, o distribute alinha mas a ultima linha fica errada. Mas o both funciona perfeitamente quando se usa a section principal. Por isso o meu não esta dando certo, porque eu tenho este alinhamento numa section criada com o createTextRun(), e aí ele não aceita a formatação. Eu preciso desse createTextRun() pois tenho que negritar palavras chaves dentro do texto.

Comment: Consegui fazer a justificacao passando o estilo dentro do metodo createTextRun(), da seguinte forma: 
$doc = $section->createTextRun(array('align' => 'both'));

dessa forma ele coloca toda a sessao $doc no formato passado.

Comment: @Leandro que bom que conseguiu.